# GNUPG - stdin encrypted file and passphrase on windows

Tags: windows, gnupg

How can I pipe the passphrase and encrypted file in gpg.exe?

I have tried a few different combinations but I can't get it to work.

Here is my attempt,

```
C:\>gpg.exe --output [OUTPUT_FILE] --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt < [INPUT_FILE] < [PASSPHRASE_FILE]
```

from this I get error

```
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
```

Swapping the input and passphrase around I get the error

```
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: decrypt_message failed: eof
```

If I don't try and send the encrypted file via stdin then the decryption works fine.

Ultimately what I want to do is decrypt a file based on a file mask with the date timestamp in the file name. Outlined below,

```
C:\>gpg.exe --output yyyyMMdd.csv --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt < *_yyyyMMdd_*.txt < [PASSPHRASE_FILE]
```

I'm not sure if this will work because I can't get the basic scenario working, I would also appreciate if someone could advise me of the best way to achieve this.

Comment: How do I get gpg.exe compiled for Windows in the first place? Did you build it using mingw/cygwin/msvc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use redirection for the file you want to decrypt, only for the file containing your passphrase:

```
C:\>gpg.exe --output [OUTPUT_FILE] --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt [INPUT_FILE] < [PASSPHRASE_FILE]
```

But honestly, it might be easier for you to remove the passphrase from your key.  After all, storing your passphrase in a file is not very secure. Just change your passphrase to a blank and protect your gpg home directory to deny access to any process other than your own.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I integrating into an already existing system so I can't change the passphrase on the file.

Comment: I will use a batch or powershell script to find the file first and then use the result gpg command.

Comment: how can I decrypt to the original filename ( i dont know the original filename) ( someone encrypted 111.AAA and send it to me as 111.PGP - I want to decrypt it but i dont know that it has been AAA . how can I tell  pgp to do it automatically) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm not sure that is possible. As far as I know, the original file name is not recorded anywhere inside the encrypted file.  You might want to ask a new question.